# Scrapy doesn't stop scraping even after pagination has ended

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am experimenting with Scrapy trying it out in the following [link](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=computer+science&qt=results_page#%2528x0%253Aaudiobook%2Bx4%253Alp%2529format).

There are only 3 results pages, with the given filters. And the next link is no more active when in the last page. However, scrappy is scraping the content without stopping. Even though there is check for availability of next link to further proceed. I am not able to figure out whats wrong. And my output is having data too.

[image: The next link active in first page]

[image: The next link inactive in the last page]

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "worldcat"        
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=computer+science&qt=results_page#%2528x0%253Aaudiobook%2Bx4%253Alp%2529format',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for book in response.css('.menuElem'):
            yield {
                'title': book.css('.details .name a strong::text').get(),
                'author': book.css('.details .author::text').get(),
                'publisher': book.css('.details .publisher .itemPublisher::text').get(),
            }

        next_page = response.xpath('/html//td[@align = "right"]/a[.="Next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I also tried adding `next_page = ""` to the end of the if next_page code block with no help.

However, for some reason it works in this [link](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=%22data%22%20scraping&fq=ap%3A%22united%20states%22&dblist=638&start=21&qt=page_number_link).

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @stasiekz sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question. It does work in that case, but a small change to keyword and it doesn't. Can't figure out why.

Comment: try this XPath for finding next page: '//*[@id="donerefinesearch"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[2]/@href`

Comment: You might want to be careful. As long as you're not doing this for commercial purposes, it should be ok, but if you refer to the Worldcat Terms and Conditions page [here](https://www.oclc.org/content/dam/ext-ref/worldcat-org/terms.html) the following is prohibited:

**iv. use of bots, spiders, or other automated information-gathering devices or programming routines to "mine" or harvest material amounts of Data**.

Please make sure to be responsible when scraping from websites if you are doing it in large volume by checking their Terms and Conditions as well as Robots.txt

Comment: @esfwan No problem. I am giving out the tip because I once used scraping for a company project and had to cancel it after realizing the legal issues, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy sees page's source like the JavaScript was disabled.
Since the page you are trying to scrape has AJAX pagination it may behave differently when JS is disabled.

When you disable JS and enter [page you want to scrape](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=computer%20science&qt=results_page#%2528x0%253Aaudiobook%2Bx4%253Alp%2529format) you see there is `6,339,303` results, hence it seems to scrape infinitely.

Comment: Thanks, let me check if ajax is the issue. But why is it then working for some keywords as I mentioned in the question?

Comment: When you disable JS, you will see that results are the same at this particular URL but it is just a coincidence. However mind the terms and conditions of the service while crawling as mentioned previously.